# Dissolving large shapefiles of protected areas in R

Tags: shapefile, r, dissolve, sf

My overall aim is to measure the number of GPS points that overlap with protected areas. I am using the [protected planet database](https://www.protectedplanet.net/country/IRL) to source my shapefiles for Ireland and the UK.

I don't need any detail of the shapefiles aside from the outline and so I try to dissolve them. Indeed, if I don't do this then I encounter issues with multiparts.

My attempt seems to work for Ireland but not the UK, presumably due to the larger size of the latter. To clarify, R hangs for hours when I run it for the UK. For this code to run you'll need to download the zip from protected planet and extract the three individual files for either UK or Ireland.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

spath <- "data"
(shps <- list.files(spath, "polygons.shp$"))
mydata <- do.call(rbind, lapply(shps, read_sf))
marine_only <- mydata %>% filter(MARINE == "2") 

marine_only$GIS_M_AREA <- st_area(marine_only)
marine_only

marine_dissolved <-
  marine_only %>%
  summarise(REP_AREA = sum(REP_AREA))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that st_within() is a bit slow. Something like the procedure below might work (watch out for typos)

```
library (sf)

# extract the geometry of the conservation areas to a new variable
# to get rid of all other attributes

polygon_outlines <- st_geometry (conservation_area_polygons) %>% st_as_sf()

# add a new field to the polygon_outlines to identify points within or without
# so points that have within==1 are ... within boundaries

polygon_outlines$within <- 1   

# create a join between the points and the polygons. this adds the field 'within' 
# to the points - points within a polygon will have a value of within==1 otherwise NA

dt <- st_join (point_data, polygon_outlines)

# select the points where within!=NA

dt <- dt[!(is.na(dt$within), ]

print (nrow(dt))
```

The number of records in dt should reflect the number of points within conservation areas.